# Reorganized JSON

Tags: python, json

Need to reorganize JSON into a new structure in Python.

For example:

```
{
  'a' : 1,
  'b' : 1,
  'd' : {'d1' : '1', 'd2' : 2},
  'm' : [
    {'x' : 6, 'y' : 5, 'z' : {'foo' : 'foo1', 'bar' : 'bar1'} },
    {'x' : 8, 'y' : 8, 'z' : {'foo' : 'foo2', 'bar' : 'bar2'} }
  ]
}
```

to

```
{
  'new_a' : 1,
  'new_d' : {'new_d1' : '1', 'new_d2' : 2},
  'new_m' : [
    {'new_x' : 6, 'new_z' : {'new_foo' : 'foo1', new_'bar : 'bar1'} },
    {'new_x' : 8, 'new_z' : {'new_foo' : 'foo2', 'new_bar : 'bar2'} }
  ]
}
```

There is the idea of ​​a new form of an old JSON

**Is there a more elegant way to do that?**

```
import json

new_data = {}
new_data['new_a'] = old_data['a']
new_data['new_d'] = {}
new_data['new_d']['new_d1'] = old_data['d']['d1']
new_data['new_d']['new_d2'] = old_data['d']['d2']
new_data['new_m'] = {}
new_m = []
for m in old_data:
    new_m.append({'new_x' : m['x'], 'new_z' : {'new_foo' ....
```

Comment: Do you only want to rename?

Comment: No. remove few fields, little reorganization structure

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned a requirement that the resultant code must remove "few fields". Using a recursive loop that handles dicts and lists, we can change all keys to `new_` and remove any fields that you specify.

```
a = {
  'a' : 1,
  'b' : 1,
  'd' : {'d1' : '1', 'd2' : 2},
  'm' : [
    {'x' : 6, 'y' : 5, 'z' : {'foo' : 'foo1', 'bar' : 'bar1'} },
    {'x' : 8, 'y' : 8, 'z' : {'foo' : 'foo2', 'bar' : 'bar2'} }
  ]
}

def rename(dt):
    ndt = {}
    for k, v in dt.iteritems():
        if k == 'y':  # the keys that you wish to remove from the new dictionary
            continue
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            ndt['new_' + k] = rename(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            ndt['new_' + k] = [rename(x) for x in v]
        else:
            ndt['new_' + k] = v
    return ndt

print rename(a)  # your expected dictionary
```

If any structural reorganization needs to take place (e.g. you want to move a value somewhere else, or if you don't want to follow the naming convention that you have), then your existing code is already the cleanest way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

simple recursive solution will do:

```
def patch_keys(d, func):
    """
    For a given dictionary `d`, recursively applies `func` to its keys,
    filtering out those with `func(key)` evaluated to False. 
    For a list or tuple, applies `patch_keys` to each element.

    Intended usage:
    >>> patch_keys({1: 'a', 2: 'b'}, lambda x: x-1)
    {1: 'b'}
    """
    # we want to recursively apply self, i.e. `patch_keys(..., func=func)`
    # here functools.partial comes in handy
    self = partial(patch_keys, func=func)
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        # for a dict, apply self to values
        return {func(k): self(v) for k, v in d.items() if func(k)}
    elif isinstance(d, (list, tuple)):
        # for list and tuples, apply self to each element
        return type(d)(map(self, d))
    else:
        # else return as is
        return copy.deepcopy(d)
```

results:

```
>>> old_data = {
...   'a' : 1,
...   'b' : 1,
...   'd' : {'d1' : '1', 'd2' : 2},
...   'm' : [
...     {'x' : 6, 'y' : 5, 'z' : {'foo' : 'foo1', 'bar' : 'bar1'} },
...     {'x' : 8, 'y' : 8, 'z' : {'foo' : 'foo2', 'bar' : 'bar2'} }
...   ]
... }
>>>

>>> patch_keys(old_data, new_keys)
{'new_d': {'new_d2': 2, 'new_d1': '1'}, 'new_m': [{'new_z': {'new_foo': 'foo1', 'new_bar': 'bar1'}}, {'new_z': {'new_foo': 'foo2', 'new_bar': 'bar2'}}], 'new_b': 1, 'new_a': 1}
```